# Is it possible to run Postgres on a write-protected file system? Or a shared file system?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I'm trying to set up a distributed processing environment,
with all of the data sitting in a single shared network drive.
I'm not going to write anything to it, and just be reading from it,
so we're considering write-protecting the network drive as well.

I remember when I was working with MSSQL,
I could back up databases to a DVD and load it directly as a read-only database.

If I can do something like that in Postgres,
I should be able to give it an abstraction like a read-only DVD,
and all will be good.

Is something like this possible in Postgres,
if not, any alternatives? (MySQL? sqlite even?)

Or if that's not possible is there some way to specify a shared file system?
(Make it know that other processes are reading from it as well?)

For various reasons, using a parallel dbms is not possible,
and I need two DB processes running parallel...

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: How come you don't just access the database as a "read only" user? Also if parallelism is important, have you looked into hadoop and other distributed systems?

Comment: "For various reasons" ... ? If you explain more (on dba.stackexchange.com, the right place to ask this sort of thing) we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 3):

Write-protecting the data directory will cause PostgreSQL to fail to start, as it needs to be able to write `postmaster.pid`. PostgreSQL also needs to be able to write temporary files and tablespaces, set hint bits, manage the visibility map, and more.

In theory it might be possible to modify the PostgreSQL server to support running on a read-only database, but right now AFAIK this is not supported. Don't expect it to work. You'll need to clone the data directory for each instance.

If you want to run multiple PostgreSQL instances for performance reasons, having them fighting over shared storage would be counter-productive anyway. If the DB is small enough to fit in RAM it'd be OK ... but in that case it's also easy to just clone it to each machine. If the DB isn't big enough to be cached in RAM then both DB instances would be I/O bottlenecked and unlikely to perform any better than (probably slightly worse than) a single DB not subject to storage contention.

There's some chance that you could get it to work by:

- Moving the constant data into a new tablespace onto read-only shared storage
- Taking a basebackup of the database, minus the newly separated tablespace for shared data
- Copying the basebackup of the DB to read/write private storage on each host that'll run a DB
- Mounting the shared storage and linking the tablespace in place where Pg expects it
- Starting pg

... at least if you force hint-bit setting and `VACUUM FREEZE` everything in the shared tablespace first. It isn't supported, it isn't tested, it probably won't work, there's no benefit over running private instances, and I sure as hell wouldn't do it, but if you really insist you could try it. Crashes, wrong query results, and other bizarre behaviour are not unlikely.

Comment: "there's no benefit over running private instances", well, one benefit is saved storage space in really massive data sets.

Comment: @Brian In the unusual case of a read-mostly, CPU-bound workload where the storage system isn't the bottleneck, yes. In most other cases all that would get you is two machines sharing the same storage iops, plus extra overheads.

Comment: well... "a read-mostly, CPU-bound workload where the storage system isn't the bottleneck" is exactly what I have ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but it may be possible to run postgres with a data dir which is mostly on a RO file system if all your use is indeed read-only.  You will need to be sure to disable autovacuum. I think even read activity may generate xlog mutation, so you will probably have to symlink the `pg_xlog` directory onto a writeable file system. Sometimes read queries will spill to disk for large sorts or other temp requirements, so you should also link `base/pgsql_tmp` to a writeable disk area.

As Richard points out there are visibility hint bits in the data heap. May want to try [`VACUUM FULL FREEZE ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) on the db before putting it on the RO file system.

Comment: Won't work without some tweaks. Apart from sorts etc, there are "hint bits" in the data tables indicating transaction visibility stuff. You might be able to do it if all the data is tagged as "frozen" before making it read pnly.

Answer (score 0):

"Is something like this possible in Postgres, if not, any alternatives? (MySQL? sqlite even?)"

I'm trying to figure out if I can do this with postgres as well, to port over a system from sqlite.  I can confirm that this works just fine with sqlite3 database files on a read-only NFS share.  Sqlite does work nicely for this purpose.

When done with sqlite, we cut over to a new directory with new sqlite files whenever there are updates.  We don't ever insert into the in-use database.  I'm not sure if inserts would pose any problems (with either database).  Caching read-only data at the OS level could be an issue if another database instance mounted the dir read-write.  This is something I would ideally like to be able to do.

Comment: If you want PostgreSQL to be able to do this you'll need to do some significant work on the server core code, produce a quality patch, and convince the team on -hackers that this is a worthwhile feature to support into the future. Or maintain a fork. If you wanted to tackle this, you'd start with the `hot_standby` code and add options to (a) read `recovery.conf` from outside the datadir and (b) allow the postmaster to create `postmaster.pid` outside the datadir; probably more, too.

Comment: Even then the postmaster would be free to crash horribly if anyone changed the datadir contents out from under it. I don't see much of a way around that. Personally I'd actually like this feature and would be willing to help test any patch, because it'd be handy when in disaster recovery to be able to fire a `postgres` backend up against a read-only file system.